# How to create DefaultMessageListenerContainer in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, weblogic

I am new to Spring-Boot and trying to create DefaultMessageListenerContainer so I can use the weblogic workmanager and run several message listeners in multithreaded fashion.

Can someone please provide some example.
So far, I found the below solution but how do I implement this in Spring-Boot?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="receiver"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a `ConnectionFactory`:

```
  @Bean
  public ActiveMQConnectionFactory receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("yourBrokerUrl");

    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
  }
```

Create a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`:

```
  @Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory orderDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
        new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory
        .setConnectionFactory(receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");

    return factory;
  }
```

Create your `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`:

```
  @Bean
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer orderMessageListenerContainer() {
    SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint =
        new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setMessageListener(new YourMessageListener());
    endpoint.setDestination("yourDestination");

    return orderDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()
        .createListenerContainer(endpoint);
  }
```

For a more detailed example checkout this post I created on [Spring JMS listeners](https://codenotfound.com/spring-jms-listener-example.html).