# Whether topicJmsListenerContainerFactory supports asynchronous Processing - Azure Spring JMS?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I'm trying to read the messages asynchronously from azure service bus topic. I have created the JMS Listener based on MS documentation

```
  @JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
            subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
    public void receiveMessage(User user) {
        logger.info("Received message: {}", user.getName());
    }
```

I need to ensure whether topicJmsListenerContainerFactory container factory supports asynchronous  processing ?

Spring documentation says  [image]

I tried Implementing the **DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory**  like below, but by using this I can't able to fetch any messages from service bus top. It throwing an exception **The messaging entity could not be found.** I'm able to fetch messages by using **topicJmsListenerContainerFactory** container factory

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer Configure, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    Configure.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus

[How to create DefaultMessageListenerContainer in Spring-Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050440/how-to-create-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-in-spring-boot)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.servicebusjmsautoconfiguration.topicjmslistenercontainerfactory?view=azure-java-preview

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html

Any one please advise on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.
A quick look at  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/e81850c3fcebe0bbfe65ed3e8a1c7c0c607798cf/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.java#L71

Provides that `topicJmsListenerContainerFactory` is also an instance of `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` class, as we know `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` provides all the goodness of Spring JMS so it should be working fine.